# What does "subring/subfield" of $E/F$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology, extension-field

I am a bit confused with terminology. I know that "the subfield of $E/F$ generated by $S$" means $F(S)$ (the subfield of $E$ generated by $F$ and $S$), and "the subring of $E/F$ generated by $S$" is the subring of $E$ generated by $F$ and $S$.

Though in my book it was never explicitly stated what "subring of $E/F$" or "subfield of $E/F$" means. Can someone please explicitly state the meaning of the two?

Comment: For $\alpha $ algebraic over a field $F$ then $F(\alpha) = F[\alpha] = F[x]/(h(x))$ (its minimal polynomial) and $ F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) = F[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n] = F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$. You'll look also at $\mathbb{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *subring* of $E/F$ is just a ring $R$ such that $F \subseteq R \subseteq E$. Also called an *intermediary ring*.

A *subfield* of $E/F$ is just a field $K$ such that $F \subseteq K \subseteq E$. Also called an *intermediary field*.